# ¿Cuándo puedo usar 'dificultoso' en vez de 'difícil'?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, adjetivos, sinónimos

No entiendo la diferencia, si la hay, entre el uso de las dos palabras: *dificultoso* y *difícil*. Según el DLE:

> [dificultoso](https://dle.rae.es/?id=DjySkwD): Difícil, lleno de impedimentos
>
> [difícil](https://dle.rae.es/?id=DjoVnu9): Que presenta obstáculos (‖ impedimentos).

¿Hay contextos más adecuados para el uso de 'dificultoso'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Dificultoso* se relaciona con esfuerzos prolongados, con procesos con varias etapas, con acciones mecánicas repetidas. Tiene sinónimos como *trabajoso*, *laborioso*, etc., que también sugieren estas cosas. Por ejemplo:

- *La travesía fue muy dificultosa.*
- *Se le hizo dificultosa la respiración.*
- *Subimos dificultosamente las escaleras.*

*Difícil* es una palabra más común y genérica. Casi siempre que se dice *dificultoso* se puede reemplazar por *difícil*, pero no al revés. Por ejemplo, se puede decir *«una persona difícil»*, pero no *«una persona dificultosa»*, porque *ser díficil*, aplicado al carácter de una persona, tiene un significado especial.

Ante un problema matemático diremos generalmente que es o parece *difícil*, no *dificultoso*, porque *difícil* es preferible cuando hablamos de algo estático, una situación que tenemos frente a nosotros, algo *a priori*. Diremos que un problema es *dificultoso* cuando resulte difícil resolverlo, *a posteriori*.

Con los adverbios *difícilmente* y *dificultosamente* ocurre que no pueden casi nunca intercambiarse entre sí:

- *difícilmente* = "muy poco probablemente"
- *dificultosamente* = "con dificultad"

Answer (score 3):

La respuesta rápida es: cuando quieras puedes usar una de las dos; simplemente **dificultoso** agrega un matiz diferente. **Difícil** es una adjetivo que cualifica y **dificultoso** podriamos decir que es algo **dificil** de manera contínua o por naturaleza.

Por ejemplo, desatar un nudo es algo **difícil** pero a manera que lo vas desenredando se va haciendo cada vez más fácil. En cambio, hacer la tarea de matemáticas es **dificultoso** si el proceso completo es difícil.

---

El uso principal que se da del sufijo **-oso** es cuando se le agrega a un sustantivo. Y significa **a manera de**, **relativo a**, **abundancia de**, etc. Así:

> **amor** se convierte en **amoroso**,
>   **gracia** en **gracioso**,
>   **aceite** en **aceitoso**,
>   **arena** en **arenoso**,
>   **calor** en **caluroso**,
>   **pereza** en **perezoso**,
>   etc.

Sin embargo, la palabra **difícil** es, por si misma, un adjetivo. Cuando al los adjetivos se les agrega el sufijo **-oso**, se les disminuye o aumenta la magnitud del adjetivo.

> **Difícil** se convertiría en **dificiloso** (aunque prefiero dificilón),
>   **verde** en **verdoso**,
>   **voluntario** en **voluntarioso**,
>   etc,

Desde mi punto de vista, **dificultoso** proviene, mas bien, del verbo **dificultar**. Cuando el sufijo se le añade a un verbo, se le da un matiz activo y progresivo. Así,

> **afanar** se transforma en **afanoso**
>   **enredar** en **enredoso**,
>   **resbalar** en **resbaloso**,
>   etc.